# extracting fields from a string

Tags: php, serialization

I am working on website in which I want to extract few fields from a string. The code which I have used to get that string is:

```
<?php 
   for ($i = 0; $i < count($data['item']->logistic_out); $i++) {
    echo strtolower($data['item']->logistic_out[$i]->logistics_times);

   }
?>
```

The above echo code is printing the following string which is logistics_times:

```
a: 7: {
    s: 3: "mon";a: 2: {
        s: 5: "start";s: 5: "09:00";s: 3: "end";s: 5: "21:00";
    }
    s: 3: "tue";a: 2: {
        s: 5: "start";s: 5: "09:00";s: 3: "end";s: 5: "21:00";
    }
    s: 3: "wed";a: 2: {
        s: 5: "start";s: 5: "09:00";s: 3: "end";s: 5: "21:00";
    }
    s: 3: "thu";a: 2: {
        s: 5: "start";s: 5: "09:00";s: 3: "end";s: 5: "21:00";
    }
    s: 3: "fri";a: 2: {
        s: 5: "start";s: 5: "09:00";s: 3: "end";s: 5: "21:00";
    }
    s: 3: "sat";a: 2: {
        s: 5: "start";s: 5: "09:00";s: 3: "end";s: 5: "21:00";
    }
    s: 3: "sun";a: 2: {
        s: 5: "start";s: 5: "09:00";s: 3: "end";s: 5: "21:00";
    }
}
```

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering what changes I should make in the code above so that its look like this:

```
mon 09:00   21:00
tue 09:00   21:00
```

I am pretty sure I have to use [unserialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) method but I am not sure how I can use it efficiently in the code above.

Comment: That data looks like it might be the result of a `serialize()` on an array. Is that the case??

Comment: i am not sure but `logistics_times` is getting pulled from the database,

Comment: Start by doing a simple `print_r(unserialize($data['item']->logistic_out[$i]->logistics_times));` and seeing what the array looks like#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you should unserialize it. Don't echo out your string, simply append them into a variable. So, like this:

```
<?php 
   $serialized = '';
   for ($i = 0; $i < count($data['item']->logistic_out); $i++) {
    $serialized .= strtolower($data['item']->logistic_out[$i]->logistics_times);
   }
?>
```

Then, unserialize it and it will turn into an array:

```
$unserialized = unserialize( $serialized );
```

Now you can loop through your array via `foreach` to print out what you need.

Please be aware that if there is even one tiny error in your serialized string, it will not work. The fact that you are manually building a serialized string is a bit worrying, and you may possibly need to assess if there is a better starting point here.

Comment: Just a thought, each iteration of `logistics_times`  is probably a unique `serialize()` So you might be better suggesting the `unserialize()` gets done as part of the loop and not on an amalgamation of all the serialised arrays which definitely wont work

Comment: @RiggsFolly I am wondering what will be the right way to unserialize the string. I am pretty sure I have to use something like this 

`$data = unserialize(str_replace(' ', '', $str));
foreach($data as $key=>$value)
{
    echo $key." ".$value['start']." ".$value['end']."<br/>";
}`  but I am not sure how I can fit in the actual code.

Comment: @flash Yes I am here

Comment: @RiggsFolly Can you give me a pointer how can I print  `mon 09:00   21:00
tue 09:00   21:00` ? Any thoughts ?

Comment: @flash ahh no sorry got to go to a meeting

Comment: No problem @RiggsFolly

Comment: I will look back at this later if i get time

Comment: @RiggsFolly Thanks